# output is empty when using string split in java

Tags: java, string, split

I am using

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        String str = "12,23,34,65,67,87,98,78,09,31,56,98,45";

        String s1[] = str.split(str,3);

         for(String s:s1)
             System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

But the output is  empty.I am getting empty console.But when i print the `s1` array length it is giving 2 for me.What is the wrong here.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You're splitting the string on itself, what are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting 12 23 34 as output

Comment: i want to get each time 3 numbers

Comment: @jlordo thank u .I got it.I need to use str.split(",",3);

Comment: @PSR you will get `12
                  23
                  34,65,67,87,98,78,09,31,56,98,45` by this

Comment: @Ruchira actually i need to iterate for every three element .How i can do this?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please post the exact expected output for the input you posted as part of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [string split with start and end index in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636401/string-split-with-start-and-end-index-in-java)

Comment: @PSR can you post the exact output you expect in your question otherwise this question is only suitable to be closed

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. It appears you want to split the `String` for every 3 numbers. For this you can use

```
String[] s1 = str.split("(?<=\\G\\d+,\\d+,\\d+)");
```

Comment: Although, I would use `String[] s1` instead of `String s1[]`.

Comment: @ThomasMueller is there any major difference between them

Comment: @PSR There is no functional difference, but `String s1[]` is just supported for C compatibility and, and [it's usage is discouraged in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 0):

You will get following out put by using `str.split(",",3);`

```
12
23 
34,65,67,87,98,78,09,31,56,98,45
```

If you want to get

```
12
23
34
```

You can try something like this

```
String str = "12,23,34,65,67,87,98,78,09,31,56,98,45";
String s1[] = str.split(",",3);
for(String s:s1)                          {
   System.out.println(s.substring(0,2));
}
```